How to use SciChart/JS in Blazor .Net6/8 pages
After struggling with NRTDP/SciChartBlazor, i've tried SciChart/JS with blazor - and it works fine, with easy.
I tried to contribute to SciChartBlazor, and after seeing the internals of it - it's not covering SciChart API and you'll need/end-up adding JS anyway to support what you need.
So, here is how one can... Get SciChart/JS with blazor-server-app works.

Get SciChart/JS with blazor-server-app work:

works with .Net6+8 as of to the day written.

Pages_Layout.cshtml
<head>
...
    
    <!-- Reference the latest version is not recommended for production! -->
    @* <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/scichart/index.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> *@
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/scichart@3.3.577/index.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="~/MySciChartGraphsApi.js"></script>

    <component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
</head>

wwwroot\MySciChartGraphsApi.js
function helloSciChart() {
    return "SciChart-world";
}


// Create a SciChartSurface in the div 'scichart-root'
async function initSciChart() {
    // based on: 
    // * https://www.scichart.com/getting-started/scichart-javascript/
    // ** https://codepen.io/scichart/pen/eYPXazY

    const {
        SciChartSurface,
        NumericAxis,
        FastLineRenderableSeries,
        XyDataSeries,
        EllipsePointMarker,
        SweepAnimation,
        SciChartJsNavyTheme,
        NumberRange,
        MouseWheelZoomModifier,
        ZoomPanModifier,
        ZoomExtentsModifier
    } = SciChart;

    // Tell SciChart where to get webassembly files from.
    SciChartSurface.useWasmFromCDN();

    // Initialize SciChartSurface. Don't forget to await!
    const { sciChartSurface, wasmContext } = await SciChartSurface.create("scichart-root", {
        theme: new SciChartJsNavyTheme(),
        title: "SciChart.js First Chart",
        titleStyle: { fontSize: 22 }
    });

    // Create an XAxis and YAxis with growBy padding
    const growBy = new NumberRange(0.1, 0.1);
    sciChartSurface.xAxes.add(new NumericAxis(wasmContext, { axisTitle: "X Axis", growBy }));
    sciChartSurface.yAxes.add(new NumericAxis(wasmContext, { axisTitle: "Y Axis", growBy }));

    // Create a line series with some initial data
    sciChartSurface.renderableSeries.add(new FastLineRenderableSeries(wasmContext, {
        stroke: "steelblue",
        strokeThickness: 3,
        dataSeries: new XyDataSeries(wasmContext, {
            xValues: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
            yValues: [0, 0.0998, 0.1986, 0.2955, 0.3894, 0.4794, 0.5646, 0.6442, 0.7173, 0.7833]
        }),
        pointMarker: new EllipsePointMarker(wasmContext, { width: 11, height: 11, fill: "#fff" }),
        animation: new SweepAnimation({ duration: 300, fadeEffect: true })
    }));
  
    // Add some interaction modifiers to show zooming and panning
    sciChartSurface.chartModifiers.add(new MouseWheelZoomModifier(), new ZoomPanModifier(), new ZoomExtentsModifier());

    return "done";
};

CSS-file
.MyGraph { height: 400px; }

Your-Page.razor / HTML
<div id="scichart-root" class="MyGraph"></div>

Your-Page.razor.cs
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        try
        {
            // string result2 = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("helloSciChart");  // checking JS works
            string result3 = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("initSciChart");

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Logger.LogError("exception: {exception}", exception);
        }
    }

    await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
}

Expected result.

BONUS for using SciChart/JS

You can copy-paste SciChart examples, and they’ll work immediately.
Not dependant on other
If SciChart release new API-features, you can use them immediately in your app.

HTH.
